# Getting Read/Write access error when trying to use method from external library

Tags: c++, memory-management, managed-c++

I am trying to use the following implementation from a library

[image]

**C++**

```
int CALLBACK xCallback(long xmitlen, int buflen, char *buf, long flen)
{
    return 0;
}

extern "C"  __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall TXFIlestransfer(int port, string fileName);

__declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall TXFIlestransfer(int port, string fileName)
{
     int ret;

     char *test = &fileName[0];

     ret = sio_FtKermitTx(port, test, xCallback, 27);

     return ret;
}
```

I am importing this to use with C# and am getting System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'

[image]

Any help with resolving this error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is TXFIlestransfer properly executed while you're in debug mode? btw you have probably a typo in TXFIle... where "i" in "File" is typed in capital letter

Comment: Try passing instead of char* test to the function sio_FtKermitTX some literal string like "myfile.aaa" and see if you get the same error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your program by simulating the `sio_FtKermitTx` function in my C++ dll (**Mydll.dll**):

```
int sio_FtKermitTx (int port, char *fname, int (CALLBACK *func) (long xmitlen, int buflen, char *buf, long flen), int key)
{
    return 5;
}
```

**And even with an empty body, I have the same problem as you.**

After several investigations, I noticed that the problem came from the fact that we are using a `string` object between `C#` and `C++` code which for one reason or another (unicode / multibyte configuration for example, or simply because sharing complex objects is difficult to implement) causes problem.

**Solution:**
By replacing the `string` object with a primitive `char` type, everything works correctly:

**C# Code:**

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace MyProgramme
{
    class Test
    {
        // Import C++ DLL
        [DllImport("Mydll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int TXFIlestransfer(int i, char[] filename);
        //public static extern int TXFIlestransfer(int i, string filename); // this crash

        static void RunTest(/*LoadFilterEVENTMessage msg*/)
        {
            string c = "ABC";
            char[] char_arr = c.ToCharArray();
            int i = TXFIlestransfer(3, char_arr);
            // int i = TXFIlestransfer(3, c); string version crash

            string s = i.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(s);
        }

        /* Methods in DLL being used below  */
        public static void Main()
        {
            RunTest();
        }
    };
}
```

**C++ DLL code (Mydll.dll) :**

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int TXFIlestransfer(int port, char fileName[])
{
    int ret;
    char *test = &fileName[0];
    ret = sio_FtKermitTx(port, test, xCallback, 27);
    return ret;
}
```

anyway, your `sio_FtKermitTx` function accepts a `char*` in parameter, so changing your `TXFIlestransfer` parameters from `string` to `char[]` is not problematic.

**Result:**
After running C# program you will get this:

[image]